# docker-py : Docker Python sdk container.put_archive not working

Tags: python, docker, containers

I have copied a example.py file from local system to container using put_archive under /root/ directory. I want to run the file in container. The file is not found in container. Here is my code: What's wrong in my code ? I expect put_archive should copy a file example.py under /root directory. The file is not found in container.

```
import docker
import os
import tarfile
import time
import json
from io import BytesIO

client = docker.from_env()
image = client.images.pull("malark79/ibm-cloud-python-sdk")

container = client.containers.run("malark79/ibm-cloud-python-sdk", "pwd", detach=True)
print("Docker logs: " + str(container.logs()))

print(container.id)
print(container.name)
print(container.image)

f = open("example.py", "w") //open local file
with tarfile.open("example.py.tar.gz", "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(f.name, arcname=os.path.basename(f.name))
t = open("example.py.tar.gz", "rb")

works = container.put_archive("/root/", data=t)

t.close()
if not works:
        print("Can't create file in container")

container = client.containers.run("malark79/ibm-cloud-python-sdk", "ls -al /root", detach=True)
print("Docker logs: " + str(container.logs())) ### does not display file example.py

container = client.containers.run("malark79/ibm-cloud-python-sdk", "/usr/bin/python3 /root/example.py", detach=True)
print("Docker logs: " + str(container.logs()))  ### [Errno 2] No such file or directory\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue after 1 day of working. The container should be running for put_archive() command to work.

My container was not running, so it did not work.

Here is the working code:

```
import tarfile
import time
import json
from io import BytesIO

client = docker.from_env()

image = client.images.pull("malark79/ibm-cloud-python-sdk")
for container in client.containers.list():
  print(container.id)
  print(container.name)
  print(container.image)

container = client.containers.get(container.id)

def copy_to(src, dst):
    name, dst = dst.split(':')
    container = client.containers.get(name)

    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(src))
    srcname = os.path.basename(src)
    print("src " + srcname)
    with tarfile.open("vpc-example.tar", 'w') as tar:
        try:
                tar.add(srcname)
        finally:
                tar.close()

    with open('vpc-example.tar', 'rb') as fd:
            ok = container.put_archive(path="/", data=fd)
            if not ok:
                raise Exception('Put file failed')
            else:
                print("no exception")

copy_to("./vpc-example.py", container.name+":/vpc-example.py")

cmd="/usr/bin/python3 /vpc-example.py"

code, str = container.exec_run(cmd)
print(code)
print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to copy code into Docker space and run it, a Docker image is a better technical match.  This Python code corresponds pretty much exactly to the Dockerfile:

```
FROM malark79/ibm-cloud-python-sdk
WORKDIR /root
COPY example.py .
CMD /usr/bin/python3 /root/example.py
```

Typically I'd run `docker build` and refer to the built image in my final code, without trying to manually copy the script in.  If you need to rebuild the image every time there is a [`client.images.build()`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.build) method that can do it.

In your example code, each time you call `client.containers.run()`, you're creating a new container.  You should be able to see this if you run `docker ps -a` (or call `client.containers.list(all=True)`).  The last two commands are running on the unmodified base image, without the application code copied in.

Comment: The image is built already. I want to copy the file from local system to container.

Comment: The file in local system contains a short lived password. So, I cannot build it as image and push to docker hub.